# Is there a way to pass a function that requires args, without args and add them later?

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

Is there a simple way in python to pass a function requiring args, as a parameter without args, and add te args in the destination function? I'm thinking of something like:

```
def add(a,b):
    return a + b


def multiply(a,b):
    return a * b


def destination(variable, func):
    c = 5
    d = 3
    e = func(c , d) * variable
    return e


s = 10
output1 = destination(s, add())
output2 = destination(s, multiply())
```

Comment: You would just pass `add` and `multiply` as your parameters, with no parentheses.

Comment: Yes, but remove the `()` in your last two lines, since you don't want to actually call the function yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea but instead of passing the function into destination as an argument, you're trying to call it and pass the return value as an argument instead.

Try this: `output1 = destination(s, add)`

Answer (score 2):

`()` is actually an operator that means "call this object" when suffixed to a name. Everything between the parens is interpreted as an argument list. The object can be a function or an instance of a different class that implements the magic `__call__` method.

When you do `add()`, you're calling the `add` function with no arguments. But the name `add` itself is just another object in python. You can pass it around, use it as any other name, and call it with an argument list.